# SPFx packages are referencing older versions

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-on-prem

I have created a new solution with option `SharePoint 2016 onwards, including 2019 and SharePoint online`. Then I have added a web part and did the gulp serve.
I got below error:

[image]

Now I checked the package.json file then it is showing as below.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/generator-sharepoint": "^1.8.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0-0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "0.14.46",
    "@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15",
    "@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "0.14.46"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2"
  }
```

it is referencing older sharepoint framework packages. I have done so many solutions in my machine earlier. I am not sure whats wrong I have done here.

Update: I have tried to update the framework version as `npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint`, but nothing is updating in package.json file

Can anyone suggest me!!

Comment: Have you changed local workbench's URL or any other change in config file?

Comment: What is the version of nodejs? To update the framework version, try this: `npm install -g  @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest`.

Comment: nodejs version 8x and 10x is supported.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, I have tried with latest command only but nothing got changed.I haven't modified anything in local workbench.

Comment: @sharepoint_geek node version is 8.15.1

Comment: SP2019 version is brand new dev setup. Do I need to install any CUs to make SP2019 up to date date?

Comment: For nodejs version 8.15.1 the version of SPFx generator which works best is 1.6...try using it once.